# Инициализацие переменной пользователем java?

Tags: java

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что это значит:

java Program --current-folder=C:/MAIN

возможно это инициализация переменной пользователем, но как в коде сказать, что эта переменная инициализируется при запуске программы?

Comment: Цель: получить из --current-folder=C:/MAIN, значение после символа '=', то есть "C:/MAIN".
И казалось бы, было бы логичнее написать просто: "java Example C:/MAIN", вместо того, что бы потом это дело парсить. НО! здесь дается именно так, как я написал выше. Должна же быть тому причина...
В Си такая штука точно есть, где, то ли при компиляции, то ли при запуске программы (уже не помню), переменной, которую в коде специально оставили пустой, присваивается значение. А в Яве пока не знаю как это делается, и вот наткнулся...

Comment: Если вам необходимо получить значение после `=`, проще всего распарсить строку.
`String result = args[0].substring(args[0].indexOf('=')+1, args[0].length();`
Для данного примера в переменной `result` будет `C:/MAIN`

Answer (score 1):

Это не объявление переменной, а передача программе аргумента. Его можно получить из массива args, передаваемого в метод main:

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(args[0]);
    }
}
```

Команды:

> javac Example.java
> java Example --current-folder=C:/MAIN

Вывод:

> --current-folder=C:/MAIN

Каждый аргумент в массиве записывается в команде через пробел.

Пример использования аргументов:

```
public class Example {
    private static String currentFolder = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        parseArgs(args);
        System.out.println("Программа запущена с currentFolder = '" + currentFolder + "'");
        // Код
    }

    public static void parseArgs(String[] args) {
        for (String argument : args) {
            String[] splitted = argument.split("=");
            if (splitted.length != 2) {
                System.out.println("Некорректно составлена команда");
                return;
            }
            if (!splitted[0].equals("--current-folder")) {
                System.out.println("Несуществующая команда: " + splitted[0]);
                return;
            }
            currentFolder = splitted[1];
        }

    }
}
```

Код довольно объёмный, но ручной парсинг выглядит примерно так.

Comment: Плохо я вопрос задал. Добавил комментарий

Comment: Я дополнил ответ, надеюсь, понял вас правильно.

Answer (score 0):

Штука, которая избавляет от постоянного парсинга аргументов, называется jcommander (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.beust/jcommander)

Всем спасибо.